# Redirect extension through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all "com" extensions to "org" extensions, even if they are https. This is what I have so far...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.domain.org [R=301,L]
```

The problem is, this only redirects if it is "http". How can I also redirect if it is an https domain?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank You Much.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
RewriteRule .* http%2://www.domain.org [R=301,L]
```

The second condition creates a capture group in the event that `HTTPS` is "on", otherwise, there is no capture group. The "s" is captured and then backreferenced using `%2`.

Additionally, you can redirect the URI as well by changing the rewrite rule line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This sends me to a page that says my site is labeled as potentially unsafe

Comment: And it crosses out my https

Comment: Then if I proceed it says access forbidden

Comment: @JuanGonzales do you have a certificate that is registered for both the .com and .org sites?

Comment: No just the .org site which is why I am redirecting everything