# Redirect multiple domains to folder + non-www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm using multiple domains and redirecting them to individual folders on my server.

I'm using .htaccess to do the redirect. I've managed to do the redirects but am to redirect non-www to www. So if somone typed in domain.com or domain.co.uk I'd like them to redirect to www.domain.com or www.domain.co.uk. Would appreciate some assistance please. Here's the code

```
# pointing for the domain domain.com or domain.co.uk to folder domain
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [OR]
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [OR]
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domain/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468391/redirect-extension-through-htaccess/19468407#19468407 answers your question. Replace `domain.com` in that example with `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# redirect non-www to www
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [OR]
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk [OR]
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domain/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Appreciate it Amine. Thank you

Comment: Question, will the above hurt SEO as both domains are pointing to the same content?

Comment: not sure about that, you can create a new question in webmasters.stackexchange.com