# How to redirect one domain to another, non-www to www, and enforce SSL with .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to handle 3 rewriting tasks within my .htaccess file:

1. Redirect example1.com to example2.com
2. Redirect non-www to www
3. Redirect http to https

Yes, I realize that all of these questions have been asked and answered individually on here, but I'm trying to understand how to combine those answers together for the most efficient rewriting possible. Also, when I try to implement individual rewrites for each of these #1 or #2 or #3 they conflict with each other and send me into a redirect loop.

The closest I could find was from **Amine Hayyoussef**: [Redirect multiple domains to folder + non-www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478204/redirect-multiple-domains-to-folder-non-www-to-www)

> ```
> # redirect non-www to www
> ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
>
> ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [OR]
> ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.co.uk [OR]
> ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domain/
> ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/$1 [L]
> ```

This is what I currently have in my .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect example1.com to www.example2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example2.com [R=301,L]

# Redirect www.example1.com to www.example2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example2.com [R=301,L]

# Force non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The problem is that this fails to rewrite anything when navigating to http://www.example2.com when it should enforce SSL and rewrite to https://www.example2.com.

Ultimately, I'm sure there's a cleaner way to approach solving all 3 rewrites with a more efficient bit of code. Interested in recommendations on combining these bits of logic or keeping them seperate for ease of maintainability.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the 3 redirects can be done in a single redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example1\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure this is top most rule and you test it from a new browser.

**This assumes that both `example1.com` and `example2.com` are on same host and pointing to same directory.**

Comment: This almost works. The only edge case I could find was that http://www.example2.com does not redirect to https://www.example2.com.

Comment: Your updated code results in an error: too many redirects. It seems to have created an infinite loop.

Comment: Apache 2.4.34, not connecting from behind a proxy

Comment: Done (network log: https://imgur.com/a/4DFUR2n) and it appears that it's a 301 on www.firstperson.is. For perspective, example2.com in your code is firstperson.is in the production environment.

Comment: Still getting the same redirect loop of 301 redirects.

Comment: Same result, too many redirects. What is %{REQUEST_SCHEME} doing? Checking if the request is http vs https?

Comment: Yes that's right and it was added in Apache 2.4. Both `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` and `%{HTTPS}` work fine on my Apache 2.4 which is the reason I am suspecting that your hosting provider is behind some proxy

Comment: Double checked, sorry, this host is behind a load balancer where the SSL is terminated. So all traffic from the load balancer to the host is http. Is this what's causing the redirect loop?

Comment: Right that's what I was suspecting. Does load balancer set any other header to indicate https traffic?